# Safari rendering bug / z-index issue

Tags: html, css, safari, rendering, z-index

I'm writing my first webpage and while I am content with what I got so far my website behaves strangely in Safari. AFAIK Safari and Chrome both use the webkit engine, but Chrome renders everything the way I want it. Safari doesn't.

At the bottom of my page I have a fixed gradient div (#gradient_transition_bottom) that makes the text fade out smoothly when scrolling. Below that div is a #footer div that marks the end of my webpage. Now when I visit the webpage in Safari and scroll to the bottom the footer is covered by the gradient. When I reload the page in that position (scrolled all the way to the bottom) the footer appears and covers the bottom part of the gradient (that's how it should be).

Here are two pictures so that you understand what I mean:

After initially loading the page. How it should not be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTVte.png

After reloading all the way scrolled to the bottom. How it should be and how all other browsers, including chrome, render the webpage:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIMmN.png

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
 <foot>
        <div id="gradient_transition_bottom"></div>    
        <div id="footer">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor. &copy; 2014</div>
 </foot>
```

and CSS:

```
#gradient_transition_bottom {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 122px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    clear:both;
    color: #666;
    font: 100 0.8em "Avenir Next", Raleway, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
}
```

Is there something I can do to fix this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks odd beacause of the 80% width of the footer, but the z-index is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/6N4ke/3/ Could it be that some content wrapper is pushing into the footer? Please reproduce in the demo.

Comment: please post more of your layout in a jsFiddle to reproduce the problem

Comment: I do have my content in a wrapper but I assigned an 18px margin at the bottom so that the wrapper doesn't interfere with the content. http://jsfiddle.net/mb48r

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter too quickly and I couldn't edit fast enough. Tell me if you need more. Thanks for your help. =)

Comment: your welcome and thank you. In Safari and chrome this demo works correct. Footer over fade out. Is it broken for you?

Comment: Well when I open http://jsfiddle.net/mb48r/3/embedded/result/ in Safari it looks fine just as it does in other browsers. But jsfiddle doesn't exactly behave like what I coded, does it? For my webpage it still doesn't work. But what is weird to me is that it's only Safari. How can that be? I thought Chrome and Safari share the same engine...?

Comment: When i remember correctly google is developing an own webKit fork since late '13. But i don't think either of them will have such massive bugs. There have to be somthing weired in your coding. Please give a demo that reproduces the problem or i can't help you.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Even when I enter my whole HTML and CSS in jsfiddle it renders it correctly.